# Close random 'PopUps'

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. I have created WebDriver tests which run for the same duration.
2. Some of the tests lest say ‘PopupX’ will appear at 30 seconds.
3. On some of the test ‘PopupX’ will appear at 60 Seconds
4. On some of the test ‘PopupX’ will appear at 35 Seconds
5. You understand the id.
6. The popup always has a unique Id being the ‘X’ to close the application and even different popups have the same ‘X’ close option.
7. **Does anyone know of a way to constantly search and close ‘A form of continuous polling’ which will close the popup if it was to appear at anytime in any of the test cases?**

[image]

8. I know the following method listed below works and can successfully close the popup:

   ```
   public void closeGiveawayPopup() throws InterruptedException {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   try {
       List<WebElement> elements = wait
               .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".close")));
       for (WebElement element : elements) {
           if (element.isDisplayed()) {
               element.click();
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(elements));
               Thread.sleep(2000);
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw (e);
   }
   ```
9. I have tried to add the following method below in the TestNG 'BeforeMethod' annotation but the url dosnt even load:

   ```
   public void closeGiveawayPopup() throws Exception {
   try {
       List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".close"));
       for (WebElement element : elements) {
           if (element.isDisplayed()) {
               element.click();
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw (e);
   }
   ```

   }
10. Details of the popup have been listed below:
    [image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong Phil. @BeforeMethod annotation is the way to go. The only thing that needs improving is to include (if you don't have it already) a @BeforeClass annotation for your browser startup/shutdown respectively. Perhaps, this is why 'the browser does not even open' as you mention in your description above. So something like this:

```
@BeforeClass    
    public void initialSetup(String browser){

        Webdriver driver = new browser ();
        driver.get("https://www.buyagift.co.uk/");
   }


  @BeforeMethod 
  public void closeGiveAwayPopup(){
  //same as your code 
  }

  @Test(priority=1)
  public void makeSureIarrivedOnTheHomePage(){
  titleGrabbed = driver.getTitle().toString();
  titleExpected = "Experience Days and Gifts from Buyagift";
  Assert.assertEquals(titleGrabbed ,titleExpected )
  }

  @Test(priority=2)
  public void clickLoginButton(){
  //more actions
  }

@AfterClass
  public void shutDown(){

    driver.quit(); 
  }
```

The only way I can think of in order to have this 'continuous polling' effect that you are after is to make your @Test really really small (1 step at a time). This way hopefully you can achieve the desired effect. So don't bundle a lot of WebDriver actions under 1 @Test as you are increasing the risk of a pop-up appearing in the meantime.

The only thing that puzzles me is your comment 'the url does not even load'. Are you sure you are grabbing the actual pop-up and not closing the whole window?

If that is the case, or if the above does not work for you, try using Xpath instead of CSS. From your screenshot you need to expand both div[@id='competition_inner_ and outer details'] and find the close button somewhere (probably you are looking for an < input >, < i > or < button > tag, then I will be able to help you more and give you the full Xpath so you can try for yourself.

So something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='competiton_giveaway_popup']//button[@id='close']"));
```

PS. Another thing that came to mind, double check that you are using actual Testng annotations instead of Junit as it is easy to get confused and misclick sometimes when importing from IDE (I'm looking at you Eclipse!). So you can delete the @BeforeMethod annotation and write it again making sure it points to Testng.

PS2. On your step#9 you have missed the

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

line. I hope this is not the one giving you trouble, please double check and let me know.

Best of luck!

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed information and reply your help has been great!

Comment: Thx @Phil_P85 if you can hit the upvote button (arrow pointing upwards) next to my answer that will be hugely appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! :)

Comment: your welcome @Xwris Stoixeia would you be able to advice on the following ticket:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674745/my-explicit-wait-dosnt-work-at-all?noredirect=1#comment70547549_41674745

Thanks again